# How Can I Get a Row From a sheet and Use it to Add or Update a New Row on Another Sheet? (Python 3)

Tags: json, python-3.x, rest, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0

I have been looking for a solution to the situation I've briefly described in the title.  I'm trying to use a `smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_row()` request from one sheet, take that data and either add it or update it to a new row on a sheet where I can use a location specifying attribute to place it in a spot that isn't just the bottom of the sheet.  I know that I can copy rows from one sheet and paste them to another with code, but I am trying to bypass the "only copy at the end of the sheet" limitation.  Is this even possible, or am I grasping at straws? Here is my code that I have been working with:

```
row_a = smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_row(
  2896510686914436,       # sheet_id
  6830091038549892,       # row_id
  include='discussions,attachments,columns,columnType'
)
row_a.sibling_id = 3539932199446404
#if row_a.isinstance('parent_id',int)
#row_a.created_at = new_time
#row_a.modified_at = new_time
row_a.above = False
#row_a.row_number = None
#row_a.parent_id = None
row_a.id = 7015416612448132 #id of new row

# Add rows to sheet
response = smartsheet_client.Sheets.update_rows_with_partial_success(
  731362710841220,        # sheet_id of sheets we are adding to
  [row_a]
  )

print("Done!")
print(row_b)
```

There's a lot going on right now, but my original plan was to `get_row` then append the `sibling_id` and `.above` of where I want my new row to go, and then simply add a row of the row object I just built. Instead, I received parsing errors:

```
`{"response": {"statusCode": 400, "reason": "Bad Request", "content": {"errorCode": 1008, "message": "Unable to parse request. The following error occurred: Field \"createdAt\" was of unexpected type.", "refId": "1eyronnlz32sw"}}}`
```

My next thoughts were to append the `created_at` attribute to be the same as real time, but then `modified_at` started becoming the error.  So I did the same thing again, and then the new error became "invalid row location: specify above or below with `siblingId` You cannot use other location specifiers in the same request."

No matter what I seem to do from this point, nothing works. Even if I set "other location specifiers" like `row_number` and `parent_id` to `None`, I'm just told that `"The attribute(s) row.id, row.createdAt, row.modifiedAt, row.columns[], row.sheetId, row.version, row.accessLevel are not allowed for this operation."`

Nothing seems to be just quite right for this operation.  If anyone can offer any insight relating to my situation or just helpful tips in general, I am all ears.

Thank you!

Comment: Please note, I just added some sample code to the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend trying to use the response from a **Get Row** operation to create a new row (**Add Row**) in a sheet. Reason being -- you're likely to encounter issues (as you've described) caused by the fact that not all row attributes can be *set*.

For example, `createdAt` and `modifiedAt` will be included in the **Get Row** response, but cannot be specified in an **Add Row** or **Update Row** request -- because they are read-only attributes that are set automatically by Smartsheet when a row is created or modified.

That's exactly what the error message `"The attribute(s) row.id, row.createdAt, row.modifiedAt, row.columns[], row.sheetId, row.version, row.accessLevel are not allowed for this operation."` is trying to tell you -- those are all read-only row attributes that are set automatically by Smartsheet -- trying to set them via an **Add Row** or **Update Row** request will always result in this error.

Copying a row from one sheet to a specified position in another sheet can be accomplished by a two-step process:

1. Issue a [Copy Rows to another sheet](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#copy-rows-to-another-sheet) request to append a copy of the specified row to the bottom of the other sheet. (Note the `id` of the newly created row that's included in the response, as you'll use it in step #2.)
2. Issue an [Update Rows](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#update-rows) request -- containing attributes as described in [Specify Row Location](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#specify-row-location) -- to move the newly created row to the desired location in the other sheet.

Here's some sample code that implements the 2-step process I've described.

```
# specify source info
source_sheet_id = 3932034054809476
source_row_id = 3812039265019780

# specify destination info
destination_sheet_id = 8428033158735748

'''
STEP 1: 
    Copy row from source sheet to (bottom of) destination sheet
'''

# copy row from source sheet to (bottom of) destination sheet
# (include everything -- i.e., attachments, children, and discussions)
response = smartsheet_client.Sheets.copy_rows(
    source_sheet_id,
    smartsheet.models.CopyOrMoveRowDirective({
        'row_ids': [source_row_id],
        'to': smartsheet.models.CopyOrMoveRowDestination({
            'sheet_id': destination_sheet_id
        })
    }), 
    'all'
    )

# get the id of the newly created row
destination_row_id = response.row_mappings[0].to

'''
STEP 2: 
    Move new row from the bottom of the destination sheet
    to the desired location within that sheet. This example moves the row 
    to directly below the specified sibling row.
'''

# specify id of row that should appear directly above the row I'm moving 
sibling_row_id = 3620387999115140

# build the row to update (move)
# 'id' specifies the id of the newly created row that I now want to move
# 'sibling' attribute specifies the id of the sibling row where the row should be moved
# relative position (to sibling row) is not specified, so it will default to 'below'
row_to_move = smartsheet.models.Row()
row_to_move.id = destination_row_id
row_to_move.sibling_id = sibling_row_id

# update the row to change its location
updated_row = smartsheet_client.Sheets.update_rows(
    destination_sheet_id,
    [row_to_move]
)
```

This should get you headed in the right direction with things. If you have trouble with step 2 (successfully using location specifier attributes to move the row to the desired location), please post a new question here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for your help Kim. I will definitely be making more posts as questions arise.